# Excel, Power Query: Extract data from cell

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I want to extract data in a column within cells. Preferably in Power Query. For example this table:

|  |
| --- |
| AB ZX550D X 752 |
| AARZX580D S 859 |
| ABPZ8530D W 555 |
| ABDZ7330D D 555 |
| ABTZS530DH 857 |
| AB Z8380D W 475 |
| AB Z7480D X 475 |
| AB Z9310D D 838 |

Is it possible to extract the exact data as in the example below?

[image: Extraction example]

So, the numbers (red) are always the 3 digits before the D, but there can be multiple D's in the same cell.
Greens are always the 5th and 4th character and/or number before the D. But again, there can be multiple D's in the same cell.

Comment: Add a custom column using `Text.Range([Field],3,2)` and then use 6,3 as the start and length for the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Splitter function to split by the transition from digit to D,
then extract the appropriate places:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table39"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//Use splitter function to split on transition from digit to "D"
// then extract the appropriate text ranges
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Parts", each 
      let 
        SplitOnD = Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, {"D"})([Column1]){0},
        len = Text.Length(SplitOnD),
        part1 = Text.Range(SplitOnD,len-5,2),
        part2 = Text.End(SplitOnD,3)
      in 
        Text.Combine({part1,part2},"~"), type text),

    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Custom", "Parts", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("~", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Parts.1", "Parts.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Parts.1", type text}, {"Parts.2", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Input the data into Power Query as Range or a Table. In the advanced editor add the following code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", "Column1 - Copy"),
    #"Split Column by Positions" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Column1 - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({3}), {"Column1 - Copy.1"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Positions",{{"Column1 - Copy.1", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Column1 - Copy.1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1 - Copy.1.1", "Column1 - Copy.1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1 - Copy.1.1", type text}, {"Column1 - Copy.1.2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Column1 - Copy.1.2"}),
    #"Split Column by Position" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Column1 - Copy.1.1", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 2}, false), {"Column1 - Copy.1.1.1", "Column1 - Copy.1.1.2"}),
    #"Split Column by Position1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Position", "Column1 - Copy.1.1.2", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 3}, false), {"Column1 - Copy.1.1.2.1", "Column1 - Copy.1.1.2.2"}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Position1",{{"Column1 - Copy.1.1.1", type text}, {"Column1 - Copy.1.1.2.1", Int64.Type}, {"Column1 - Copy.1.1.2.2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type3"
```

[image]

Finally, close and load to the desired range and desired data type. Feel free to rename column names or simplify the code by removing the change data type declarations. Hope it helps!